# Access denied trying to login to Ubuntu 14.04 (Authentication with Active Directory)

Tags: linux, active-directory, ubuntu-14.04

I'm trying to set up my Ubuntu 14.04 print server to authenticate users with my Active Directory server, I've followed all of the steps using the following tutorial:

http://www.kiloroot.com/add-ubuntu-14-04-lts-server-to-a-windows-active-directory-domain-fullest-integration/#comment-15382

I've also set /opt/pbis/bin/config RequireMembershipOf $domain\\$myusergroup

When I try to login using a correct username and password, I get the message "Access denied", however when I try to connect using an incorrect password, I get the message "Invalid password." This tells me that my machine is in fact communicating with active directory, but there's something holding it back from accepting the login - maybe some sort of permission that is set incorrectly.

If anyone knows how I can fix this, please respond. Thanks ahead of time.

Comment: Ive had similar issues, ended up being my pam configuration, double check that

Answer (score 0):

try /opt/pbis/bin/config RequireMembershipOf $domain\$myusergroup